# Change Navigation Bar text colour when app launches

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I just changed the layout of my storyboard and noticed that I now have an issue with my navigation bar text colour.

This issue is that for the text colour in the navigation bar to change to the colour I want, you have to switch tabs before it will update. This wasn't an issue since the way my storyboard was laid out before meant that the first view controller that the code was in didn't have a navigation bar. However, now it is an issue and I can't figure out a way to fix it.

I have tried putting the code in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad and I wasn't able to fix the issue.

Code:

```
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = titleDict
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't fully understand your question. Try to insert your code into `awakeFromNib`, as this method is called as soon as the user touches the app icon at the home screen:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: The issue was that my navigation bar text would remain black until I switched tabs and then it would update to white. However putting the code in the awakeFromNib function fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!